# Rename a WHERE clause in SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server

I want to rename what comes up in the 'City' column in my query. Here is my data:

```
Name, Age, City
David, 20, London
Harry, 22, London
Lenny, 17, Beijing
Sally, 28, Cairo
Filo, 53, Manchester
David, 40, London
David, 30, Manchester
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT Name, Age, City
FROM [dbo].[Contacts]
WHERE City LIKE 'London'
group by City
```

Instead of 'London' coming up in the 'City' column, I want 'London David' to appear IF 'London' appears in the 'City' column AND 'David' appears in the name column.

How would I go about doing that in sqlserver?

Comment: Well trivially just ``SELECT Name, Age, 'United Kingdom'`` ?  Perhaps this is a job for a City->Country table & a JOIN.

Comment: But where would I insert 'United Kingdom' in the WHERE clause? There is no Country Column

Comment: So you don't want to group by city? You want to group by country?

Comment: Is that group by even working?

Comment: My question has changed slightly in regards that I need to change a column entry in relation to two other columns. Is that possible?

Comment: Could you just concatanate the two columns? concat(City, ' ', Name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, Age, CASE WHEN City IN ('Manchester', 'London') THEN 'United Kingdom' ELSE City END AS City
  FROM [dbo].[Contacts]
  WHERE City ='London' OR City ='Manchester'
  GROUP BY Name, Age, CASE WHEN City IN ('Manchester', 'London') THEN 'United Kingdom' ELSE City END
```

Comment: That works for a single column entry, but what if I have two? I have changed the question to make this clearer

Comment: Just add the further conditions - such as: CASE WHEN city = 'London' AND Name = 'David' THEN... WHEN...THEN...WHEN...THEN...ELSE... END

Comment: This syntax will fail on SQL Server.  You have and unaggregated `Name` and `Age` in the `SELECT`, but you aren't including them in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thx - I just extended the group by.

Comment: `LIKE` is a bit confusing in this context - actually it works in this script as `=`

Comment: Yes, this I took / copy-pasted from the original question... I will modify the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use 'United Kingdom' as your search filter in where clause you can use CTE.

```
;WITH CteCity AS(
    SELECT Name, 
        Age, 
        CASE WHEN City IN ('London','Manchester') 
            THEN 'United Kingdom' 
            ELSE City END as City
    FROM [Contacts]
)
SELECT Name, Age, City  FROM CteCity
    WHERE City ='United Kingdom'
```

As for your edited query try

```
SELECT Name, 
        Age, 
        CASE WHEN City = 'London' 
            THEN City + ' ' + Name
            ELSE City END as City
    FROM [Contacts]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE WHEN City in('London', 'Manchester') THEN 'United Kingdom' ELSE ... END as Column1
```

Answer (score 1):

This does exactly what you described, although I don´t know if that was your intent:

```
SELECT Name, Age, 
Case 
  when City='London' and Name='David' then 'London David'
  else City
end 
as City
FROM [dbo].[Contacts]
```

(Instead of 'London' coming up in the 'City' column, displays 'London David' IF 'London' appears in the 'City' column AND 'David' appears in the name column.)

I think you are mixing up:

the SELECT part -> What gets displayed of every line affected.

the WHERE Part -> Your Filter conditions, to determine which lines are affected.